# Highlight selected date in  VB.NET MonthCalendar 

Tags: vb.net

I am using MonthCalender control in vb.net to select a date. I am able to save the selected date to DB and also retrieve and bold the previous selected date. But even though date is bolded  it is not displayed when the form loads. It still highlights today's date. What Do i do to highlight the previous chosen dates.  Also i want to disable choosing date range.

I have my code below.

```
'StartDate is a datetime object

  'check if there is any date chosen
  If Not IsNothing(StartDate) Then
    Me.mcSelectedDate.AddAnnuallyBoldedDate(StartDate)
    Me.mcSelectedDate.UpdateBoldedDates()
  End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to call the [`SetDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.setdate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method or set the [`SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.selectionstart%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)/[`SelectionEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.selectionend(v=VS.100).aspx) properties to set the currently selected date:

```
'StartDate is a datetime object

  'check if there is any date chosen
  If Not IsNothing(StartDate) Then
    Me.mcSelectedDate.SetDate(StartDate)
    Me.mcSelectedDate.AddAnnuallyBoldedDate(StartDate)
    Me.mcSelectedDate.UpdateBoldedDates()
  End If
```

If you're only dealing with a single date, a [`DateTimePicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) might work instead; just ignore the time part.